# Using tikz (calendar), how can I control node positions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

Here is my code adapted from the TikZ manual. I would like to do an agricultural calendar, but I am   having trouble with the positions of the nodes. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\termin#1#2{
\node [text width= 3.4cm] at
($(cal-#1)+(0em, 0em)$) {\textcolor{red}\tiny{#2}};
 }



 \begin{document}
 \sffamily

 % A counter, since TikZ is not clever enough (yet) to handle
 % arbitrary angle systems.
 \newcount\mycount


 \begin{tikzpicture}
 [transform shape,
 every day/.style={anchor=mid,font=\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont}]
 %\node{\normalsize 2012};
 \foreach \month in
 {1,2,...,12}
 {
 % Compute angle:
 \mycount=\month
 \advance\mycount by -1
 \multiply\mycount by 30
 \advance\mycount by -90
 % The actual calendar
 \calendar at (\the\mycount:6cm)
 [
 dates=2012-\month-01 to 2012-\month-last, name=cal,
 ]
 if (day of month=1) {\tikzmonthcode}
 if (equals = 2012-11-20) [red]
 if (equals = 2012-03-10) [red] 
 if (all)
 {
 % Again, compute angle
 \mycount=1
 \advance\mycount by -\pgfcalendarcurrentday
 \multiply\mycount by 11
 \advance\mycount by 90
 \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointpolar{\mycount}{1.4cm}}
 };
 }

 \termin{2012-11-20}{\color{red}Soybean planting}
 \termin{2012-03-10}{\color{red}Soybean  harvesting}

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a parameter to the `termin` to specify positioning options. Below I have applied a `left=2.5ex` positioning to the "Soybean planting" and a `right=1.5ex` to the "Soybean harvesting".

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\termin}[3][]{%
    \node [#1] at
        ($(cal-#2)+(0em, 0em)$) {\textcolor{red}{#3}};
}


 \begin{document}
 \sffamily

 % A counter, since TikZ is not clever enough (yet) to handle
 % arbitrary angle systems.
 \newcount\mycount

\noindent
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 [transform shape, scale=0.85,
 every day/.style={anchor=mid,font=\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont}]
 %\node{\normalsize 2012};
 \foreach \month in
 {1,2,...,12}
 {
 % Compute angle:
 \mycount=\month
 \advance\mycount by -1
 \multiply\mycount by 30
 \advance\mycount by -90
 % The actual calendar
 \calendar at (\the\mycount:6cm)
 [
 dates=2012-\month-01 to 2012-\month-last, name=cal,
 ]
 if (day of month=1) {\tikzmonthcode}
 if (equals = 2012-11-20) [red]
 if (equals = 2012-03-10) [red] 
 if (all)
 {
 % Again, compute angle
 \mycount=1
 \advance\mycount by -\pgfcalendarcurrentday
 \multiply\mycount by 11
 \advance\mycount by 90
 \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointpolar{\mycount}{1.4cm}}
 };
 }

 \termin[left=2.5ex]{2012-11-20}{\color{red}Soybean planting}
 \termin[right=1.5ex]{2012-03-10}{\color{red}Soybean harvesting}

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one answer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shadings,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\termin#1#2#3#4{%
\node [align=left,text=red,font=\tiny, #2 =0ex   of cal-#1,anchor=#3] {#4};
 }%

 \begin{document}
 \sffamily

 % A counter, since TikZ is not clever enough (yet) to handle
 % arbitrary angle systems.
 \newcount\mycount


 \begin{tikzpicture}
 [transform shape,
 every day/.style={anchor=mid,font=\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont}]
 %\node{\normalsize 2012};
 \foreach \month in
 {1,2,...,12}
 {
 % Compute angle:
 \mycount=\month
 \advance\mycount by -1
 \multiply\mycount by 30
 \advance\mycount by -90
 % The actual calendar
 \calendar at (\the\mycount:6cm)
 [
 dates=2012-\month-01 to 2012-\month-last, name=cal,
 ]
 if (day of month=1) {\tikzmonthcode}
 if (equals = 2012-11-20) [red]
 if (equals = 2012-03-10) [red]
 if (all)
 {
 % Again, compute angle
 \mycount=1
 \advance\mycount by -\pgfcalendarcurrentday
 \multiply\mycount by 11
 \advance\mycount by 90
 \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointpolar{\mycount}{1.4cm}}
 };
 }

 \termin{2012-11-20}{left}{east}{Soybean planting}
 \termin{2012-03-10}{right}{west}{Soybean  harvesting}

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]